# How to get a list of uploaded images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, web

When I click on the "Send" button, need to get all the downloaded files (images) in order to transfer them to the server later. I do not know how to do it right.

It is worth noting that there is a deletion of the image by clicking on it. So just add the loaded objects to the list is unlikely to succeed. I think dictionaries would be useful here if they are in jquery.

```js
$('.product_images_button').click(function() {
  $('.product_images').click()
});

function readURL(input) {
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
    $('.blah').last().attr('src', e.target.result).css('width', '150px').css('opacity', '0.9');
  }

  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  $('.media_preview_wrap').append('<img class="blah" src="">');
  $(".product_images").val("");
}

$(".product_images").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});

$(document).on('click', '.blah', function() {
  $(this).remove()
})

$('#id_submit').click(function() {
  var data = {
    }
  console.log(data)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="media_preview_wrap">
  <div class="addPhoto">
    <div class="addPhotoHeader">
      <button type="button" class="button product_images_button">Upload image</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="file" name="image" style="display: none" required="" class="product_images" id="">
<button id="id_submit" type="button">Send</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to re-invent the wheel.

The [jQuery File Upload Plugin](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php) (by heyageek) does all that you want and is minimal and time-tested. *(I've been using it successfully for years)*

Note that he has sample code for the [client side](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php) (jQuery) and for the [server](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php) (PHP).

You will want to look at the `formData` and/or `dynamicFormData` features, which allow you to collect other data before submit and send them (along with the uploaded file) to your back-end processing file.

```
dynamicFormData: function()
{
    //var data ="XYZ=1&ABCD=2";
    var data ={"XYZ":1,"ABCD":2};
    return data;        
}
```

In js/jQuery, dictionaries (Python) are just called Objects.

Comment: Perhaps you `re right. But it's too late to go back. Will I finish the building bike)
How to get all the downloaded files? If not for the deletion, everything would be easier. I guess I can still put objects in the list. When deleting, it is easy to determine which element is deleted in DOM and delete the corresponding element from the list.

Comment: @cssyphus I would still like to refine my method without using libraries.